# Select and copy text from dialog in wxPython

Tags: select, text, dialog, wxpython, copy

I have a wxPython app, and in this app, I can select and copy text from various frames, but I can't do so from dialogs.  Is there a way to do this?

I understand I could probably do this by putting some kind of TextCtrl in the dialog, but I'd like to be able to do this from a standard looking dialog.

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I can't select text from a wx.MessageBox under Windows Vista or Mac (don't have access to Linux to try that).  Here is one example of the call to create the message box:

```
wx.MessageBox(str(msg), "Could not load ballots", wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
```

I am unable to select the text of the message box.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean when you say "copy text from various frames", etc. For example, when I run the demo (using Linux) I can copy the posted text in a Message Box, or About Box, which are both dialogs, and paste the copied into another program. What text are you trying to copy?

Comment: Even if you can't highlight the text on Windows, you can still hit Ctrl-C to copy the full contents of the dialog to the clipboard.  If you need anything more specific than that, you'll probably have to create a custom dialog with the same appearance.  wx.MessageBox is just a call to the platform's native message box function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make a custom MessageBox like so, it will appear to be static text until you click on the text:

```
class MessageBox(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_NONE)
        text.SetValue("Hi hi hi")
        text.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(4))
        self.ShowModal()
        self.Destroy()
```

I've only tested this on windows, you might have to adjust the color for your OS.

Comment: `text.SetBackgroundColour(self.GetBackgroundColour())` is probably a better fit.